# Apache Camel FTP hangs when checking for files

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

I have a Camel 2.18.5 route running on Windows 2012:

```
From[ftp://server1.com:21/test/?username=admin
password=XXXXXX
passiveMode=true
delete=true
binary=true
autoCreate=false
reconnectDelay=240000
throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true
readLock=none
localWorkDirectory=c:\ftpworkdir
scheduler=spring
scheduler.cron=0+0/10+*+*+*+MON-FRI
maximumReconnectAttempts=0
disconnect=true
soTimeout=15000
stepwise=false
doneFileName=${file:name}.SEM
include=(?i).*\.XML
To[file://c:/todir?doneFileName=${file:name}.SEM]]
```

It works most of the time, detecting and downloading files and disconnecting, but occasionally it hangs - presumably due to some network or server event. When it is hanging and I close down the program it logs:

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer : Error occurred while disconnecting from ftp://admin@server1.com:21 due: File operation failed:  Connection reset. Code: 221. This exception will be ignored.
```

So it seems that it stays connected long after the soTimeout or the default data `timeout=30000` and only disconnects after being asked to close down the route.

The `disconnectOnBatchComplete` parameter does not seem to be relevant, but I have included it in a running test none the less.

I do not have control over the FTP server.

I am looking for any suggestions on things to try - like settings or debugging methods or specific things to ask the server admins.

Comment: Are you able to try with a newer Camel release? And what do you mean by hang, does it just take a long time until it timeout, and then it continues to function. Or does it hang endless, so you must shutdown the JVM and restart the Camel application?

Comment: Upgrading the entire system would entail a 4 week test (yes I know) and since this behavior is intermittant, I would have to tie up my test environment for a long period just to test if an upgrade would help. The connection hangs until I shut down the process. It runs on Windows 2012.

Comment: We have fixed some issues in the FTP component, so chances are it works better in latest/newer release. Also mind if the "hang" is due to some firewall in the network closing connections, or if it happens after a long period of no files to download (eg inactivity) or some pattern you can see.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you trap the error and alert the operational team. Let's face it you cannot expect to fix a server out of your control but you can certainly ensure that operational teams are aware of the issue when it occurs. This might help them troubleshoot the issue and it will certainly manage the expectations of users.

Something like this(not real code just show concepts):

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <onException>
    <exception>java.io.IOException</exception> <!-- whatever exception you want to catch-->
    <log message="exception occured: ${exception}" loggingLevel="ERROR" />
    <to uri="smtp://sendmailtooperators/>
  </onException>
  <from uri="ftp://server1.com:21/test/?username=admin"/>
  <to uri="file://c:/todir?doneFileName=${file:name}.SEM]]"/>
</camelContext>
```

You could even define an errorhandler policy to retry if it hits an error three times(using redelivery policy).

Errors are going to happen and I a mature integration route will handle the most common ones and report the edge cases.

Comment: Well, the problem is that no Exception is thrown before I shut down the route by shutting down the JVM. And the exception that is thrown at that time is not very informative as you can see from the log above.

Comment: @JanLarsen so the exception is not thrown during the route running? You title mentions hanging so the route just does nothing till you stop it then throws exception?

Comment: That is correct. I have accepted that I need to upgrade Camel.